# NullPointerException without referencing any object

Tags: java, oop, exception

I have a piece of code, that throws NullPointerException sometimes. So far not really interesting. But the Exception occurs in a line, that does not reference any object.

```
    try
    {
      parser.parse(input);/*line 186*/ 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      //NPE happens in the next line?
      throw new SAXException("Error parsing document", e);/*line 190*/
    }
```

Here the Stacktrace

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tejoe.MyXMLParser.parse(MyXMLParser.java:190)
    at com.tejoe.MyXMLParser.parse(MyXMLParser.java:168)
    ....
```

It happened only twice in the last three months and the code run at least a hundred thousand times.

I already decompiled my code, to make sure the line information were correct and yes they are.

**Additional Test**

There seems to be something special with SAXException. I did the following test:

```
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    new SAXException("Error", new NullPointerException()).printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

I got the following output

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at Test.main(Test.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  ... 1 more
```

**Solution:**
SAXException overrides toString method, to return the Name of the cause Exception.

Now I only wonder, that I did not get the caused by output in the production environment (AIX JAVA)

Comment: parser.parse(input);

is parser Null?
is input Null?

Comment: Are you sure the code you are showing is from file FwXMLParser.java and not where you are using this class?

Comment: I'm not convinced decompiling will prove anything with regards to line numbers, unless it preserves white space (which I doubt).

Comment: FwXMLParser is the original class name. I change package and class to hide my company. Corrected above

Comment: Line 186 (in the source) != line 168 (in the stacktrace). Something's wrong...

Comment: Could be interresting to test with e.printStackTrace(); directly in the catch and see the output

Comment: If parser and/or input were null, the NPE should occure in line 186. But actually input can never be null, since it is iniliazied just before  InputSource input = new InputSource(new StringReader(document));. Also the parser can never be null, since it is initialized in the constructor of MyXMLParser and never changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote following code and generated null pointer exception. It came on line 45 as follow,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at inheritance.parent.Child.main(Child.java:45)

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Child  {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException {

        try{
        Child c1 = null;
        c1.i=0;

        } catch(Exception e){
            throw new SAXException("Error", e); //Line : 45
        }
    }
}
```

The error for your code is proper. You need to find which object you are getting null.

Comment: So changing the throw for a e.printStackTrace() will show the right line error

Comment: I think that is the solution. There seems to be something special with the SAXException. I get a NullPointerException in Line 45 caused by a NullPointerException in Line (c1.i=0;).When I replace SAXException by any other Exception. The other Exception is thrown with the NPE as cause. Just replace SAXException with RuntimeException and you get it. I assume, that in my code something inside the parse method fails.

Answer (score 1):

Your code must have changed since you made your last release. This will mess up the line numbers, since they are based on the code at the time it was compiled.

It looks like you've removed some code from that file since the release, meaning that the line numbers are larger than they should be.

Comment: I had the same idea, so I already checked. No, it did not change. The code is the same since 2005. I also thought that somebody may build the release with modified uncommit sources, that is why I decompiled the delivered release.

Comment: @tejoe You must be mistaken, I'm afraid. These things don't lie! Or you are looking at the wrong file, as [suggested in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564290/nullpointerexception-without-referencing-any-object/16564324#comment23798472_16564290).

Comment: SAXException does lie, because the implementation of toString() takes the name of the cause for itself. There was no NPE in line 190.

Comment: @tejoe What a fascinating outcome. How strange!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line :

```
throw new SAXException("Error parsing document", e);
```

with

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

you will find the right error line.